# How can I compare 2 library settings?

Tags: document-library

I have some issues with a library. When I create a new one and copy the documents from the old library to the new library everything is working fine. I would like to investigate what the differance is between these 2 libraries. Is there some xml I can get from a library in powershell with all the detail information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Sharepoint Manager tool to compare the properties. 
You can download it from:

http://spm.codeplex.com/

Comment: I do not compare each property with my eyes. There are to much. I would like to generate some xml with detail info. And compare it with notepad++.

Comment: Something like this but for a library: $web = Get-SPWeb http://win-ctk0o0jncig

$web.AvailableFields.SchemaXml | Out-File c:\Sitecolumns_.txt

Comment: When you select document library in sharepoint manager, you can get "SchemaXML" property. May be you can compare this